# put an image into a string of images in PHP

Tags: php, image

I Want to put an image or a label into a string of images in PHP, i search a lot but most of the people use the image library to do it. But i want to do it without using any library. For instance i have a variable named  "$img" where all the images is saved. Now if i write like so, it actually edit one image, not all the images. Can anyone have help me to solve this, so i can edit on all the images.

```
   foreach (.....) {
        // image url or image variable
        $img;

        //// image editing
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

        $imgPath = $img;
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
        $string = "MTGx";
        $fontSize = 30;
        $x = 15;
        $y = 15;
        imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
      // here it actually print a image and stop proceeding any more, why !!
        imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: You don't want to use libraries? So why are you using the GD library in your code? http://php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php

Comment: Cound you try replacing `imagejpeg($image);` to `imagejpeg($image, $filename_to_save_to);` ?

Comment: @a3ey it have exactly the same result ...

Comment: Did it save the images to the path.?

Comment: No, it did not save the image to the path, although i have a string of images, not only one image ...

Comment: What does it mean you have "a string of images"? If the images are more than one, you should store their names into an array, no? Or, if they are a unique string, you should explode them somewhere in the script. The $img variable you use is the name/path of a single image? As you are speaking about more than one image, the one saved is the first or the last? And, as you told they aren't saved, are you sure the destination folder is writeable?

Answer (score 0):

For what I can tell you are trying to output more than one image to the browser. This cannot be done. A request must return a single file (at least in PHP).